# Could I create a Postgres user without unix User?

Tags: postgresql, database

I'm newbie in Postgres and I having trouble creating users.

I have created a Unix user and a Postgres user:

```
sudo adduser aubudb
sudo -u postgres createuser --interactive # Same name
sudo -u postgres createdb aubudb
```

I can connect using `aubudb` without any problem. The point is that I want to create another user (with his own schema) **without create Unix user**.

I have run `create user dev with encoded password 'dev'` and I've added dev to the `pg_hba.conf``:

```
#host   all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    aubudb          aubudb          192.168.2.0/24          md5
host    aubudb          dev             192.168.2.0/24          md5
```

When I try to connect, I get `[28P01] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dev"` error.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can: any DB user is independed from OS user.
I bet the tricj is with the password. BTW, I do'nt see the `encoded` clause in the documentation, I bet you either meant `encrypted` or you didn't notice the error after issuing a command so the user wasn't created at all.